# How to use JavaScript in ZK Charts using Java

Tags: charts, zk

I want to know how we can write the highcharts javaScript methods in ZK charts using java. Is there any example in which i can find to write whole bunch of javaScript inside the java method??

Answer (score 0):

[Clients.evalJavaScript](https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/util/Clients.html#evalJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29) seems like what you need.